# R: Can we tell whether a function is called from within RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I want a function to use RStudio's viewer when it's called from within RStudio, and the system browser otherwise. For now I have achieved this with `try()`:

```
res <- try(rstudio::viewer(html.filepath))
if(class(res)=="try-error") {
  shell.exec(html.filepath)
}
```

But I'm thinking there might be a better solution...?

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200637288-How-to-detect-R-is-started-from-RStudio-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Roland, who pointed me to this [RStudio discussion](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200637288-How-to-detect-R-is-started-from-RStudio-), I was able to find a pretty straightforward, boolean answer to the question:

```
> nzchar(Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY")) # TRUE  when inside RStudio
                                              # FALSE when outside RStudio
```

A few other methods are given in the discussion on RStudio's site, but I like this one; it's short, straighforward and reliable as far as I can tell.

Comment: Just beware that a dedicated wiseass could throw junk into your system environmnent just to "punk" you here.  :-) .